# Criar GRANT com condição

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Eu tenho uma tabela CONDUTOR(colunas: nome, cnh, endereço, pontos_carteira) e uma GRANT analista. O analista somente podem ter acesso aos dados de condutores que possuem mais de 0 pontos na carteira.

grant select on condutor to analista with GRANT OPTION;

como encaixo uma clausura WHERE ou outro cois que resolva meu problema?

Comment: E se criar uma `view` e da permissão para a `view`, resolve?

Comment: posso tentar... mas queria saber se tem como mandar direto?

Comment: Eu acredito que não, mas vai que ...

Comment: seria o mesmo que definir permissões para registros, acho que não é possível. O melhor seria a view mesmo

Comment: Postgres ou Mysql? No postgres tem o `row level security` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html), talvez te ajude